# How do I check whether an expression attribute has been provided to a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a directive that accepts a callback as an attribute, e.g:

```
<my-directive callback-expression="someFunction()"> </my-directive>
```

The directive is reusable and hence I've given it an isolate scope. I want to show a button within the directive based on whether that `callback-expression` attribute is set.

```
App.directive('myDirective', function(){
  restrict: 'E',
  scope:    {
              callbackExpression: '&'
            },
  template: '<button ng-show="!!callbackExpression">Fire callback</button>'
});
```

The problem is, it's a function even if the expression is empty:

`console.log($scope.callbackExpression)` with a blank attribute results in:

```
function (locals) {
  return parentGet(parentScope, locals);
}
```

My current solution is to have this line at the top of my link function:

```
if (attributes.callbackExpression) scope.callbackButton = true
```

Then `ng-show` on `callbackButton`

Are there any alternatives not requiring that extra line & scope property?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid putting anything on the stack then you can use the link function where you can access the attributes via `attrs`.  Here are two approaches to that:

**Link function option 1:**

Instead of using template, you'd use this link function in your directive which conditionally adds your template:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {     
     if (attrs.callbackExpression) {
         var html = '<button>Fire callback</button>';
         element.replaceWith(html);
     }
}
```

Option 1 demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZC4MZ/2/

**Link function option 2 (better for large templates):**

For large templates you can use `$templateCache`.  First you add the template:

```
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('myDirective.html', '<button>Fire callback</button>');
});
```

Then use it conditionally just like option 1 but with a `$templateCache.get()`:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {     
    if (attrs.callbackExpression) {
        var html = $templateCache.get('myDirective.html');
        element.replaceWith(html);
    }
}
```

Making sure to inject `$templateCache` into your directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function ($templateCache) {
```

Here's a demo using `$templateCache`:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZC4MZ/3/

**Option using just the template:**

To use the template you'll need a variable on the scope. For this you can keep everything as you have it, just add:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.callbackExpression = attrs.callbackExpression;}
}
```

Template/scope variable demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZC4MZ/5/

Comment: Good to have another option, but the template in the question is not the *actual* template I'm using (the real one is much more extensive), so in practise it wouldn't be a particularly neat solution!

Comment: You could then use the $templateCache directly.  I updated the answer to include that option.

Comment: Again thanks, but it's a lot of extra overhead just to avoid adding a value to the scope. I was more wondering if there's a way to evaluate whether an attribute has been provided to a directive in the markup itself. Like this: `ng-show="!!callbackExpression"` but that works.

Comment: Updated answer which I hope gives you a good menu of what's possible within the constraints of the system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $attrs object that you can inject into in your [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) to get to this information.

Markup:

```
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <my-directive text="No Expression"></my-Directive>
    <my-directive text="Expression" callback-expression="myCallback()"></my-Directive>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){

  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      text: '@',
      callbackExpression:'&'
    },
    templateUrl: "partial.html",
    link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
      $scope.expressionCalled = false;
      if ($attrs.callbackExpression) {
        $scope.expressionCalled = true;
      }
    }
  }

});
```

I created a working plunk for this example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/K6HiT2?p=preview

Comment: I'm not sure that you read the question correctly..? This is no different than the solution I was using in the question. Also attributes *are* accessible from the link function - they're passed as the 3rd argument.

Comment: What I wanted was the ability to toggle the visibility of a callback button based on whether or not `callbackExpression` was set. I wanted to do this in as neat a way as possible, so I was wondering if putting the attribute value on the scope was really necessary.

Comment: Oh, you are right.  That is the same thing.  And thanks for pointing out about the link function.  I'll update that part of the answer. I personally dont think it is "unclean" to do it this way.

Comment: Thanks - yeah it's not too bad. I understand a lot more about angular now than I did 6 months ago :)